# mysql extract rows with max values

Tags: mysql, distinct, max

I'm trying to figure out best way to take required rows from database.

Database table:

```
id user cat time
1   5    1   123
2   5    1   150
3   5    2   160
4   5    3   100
```

I want to take `DISTINCT cat ... WHERE user=5` with `MAX time` value. How should I do that in efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use an aggregate function with a `GROUP BY`:

```
select user, cat, max(time) as Time
from yourtable
group by user, cat
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1d1a/1)

If you want to include the `id` column, then you can use a subquery:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.user,
  t1.cat,
  t1.time
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(time) Time, user, cat
  from yourtable
  group by user, cat
) t2
  on t1.time = t2.time
  and t1.user = t2.user
  and t1.cat = t2.cat
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1d1a/5).  I used a subquery to be sure that the `id` value that is returned with each `max(time)` row is the correct id.